# Exporting from QGIS to Illustrator won't include layer

Tags: qgis, export, illustrator

I created a map in QGIS with one DEM layer and several shapefile layers. When I export as SVG, it comes into Illustrator OK except for a single shp layer. The layer shows up in Illustrator's layers panel, but it's empty. I also tried exporting just the problem layer, and the same thing happens -- the layer is there, but no artwork. It's always worked for me before -- I don't get what's going on with this layer. If I open the SVG in Inkscape, it looks fine.

The map in QGIS:

[image]

The map in Illustrator:

[image]

Comment: Exporting again from Inkscape (maybe to another file format) does not help?

Comment: It looks fine in Inkscape. I solved the issue by replacing the shapefile layer in question, and everything worked fine. I'd still like to know what caused it. My guess is there was something corrupted or invalid about the layer that prevented it from being converted to SVG.

Comment: Yes, but without sharing your data, no one can tell you if something is corrupted or not...

Comment: Before exporting to SVG, try to repair the geometries of your data!

Comment: Good comments - thanks everybody.